# Post a file in JMeter with Oauth signing

Tags: oauth, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Following is what I want to implement using JMeter: I want to make a request to an API that implements OAuth signing. The API makes a POST request with a binary file.

I am trying to use OAuth Request sampler plugin. This plugin, unlike HTTP Request sampler, doesn't have 'Send Files with the Request' option.

Is there some way I can still implement it?

Comment: I think you can script the content creation, but thats not very comfortable,  of course.

Answer (score 3):

To people who might not be familiar with jmeter. Here is sample code.
Add a beanshell sampler and write in Java to sign the request and inject the authorization header into the http request sampler afterwards.

Here is the code for beanshell sampler

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;




log.info("start of signing the request");

String consumerKey = "[consumerKey]";
String consumerSecret ="[consumerSecret]";
String token = "[token]";
String secret = "[secret]"; 

OAuthConsumer consumer;
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);

HttpPost request = new HttpPost("[url]");
consumer.sign(request);

System.out.println(request.getFirstHeader("Authorization").toString());
String oauth = request.getFirstHeader("Authorization").toString().substring(15);
vars.put("oauth" ,oauth);

return oauth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try authenticating first using OAuth sampler then sending the file using regular http sampler.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with OAuth plugin. It doesn't work with latest version of JMeter. However, I got it working by writing a BeanShell Preprocessor that adds OAuth signature to the header. I, then, used default Http Request sampler.