# Jmeter OAuth 1.0a oauth_verifier

Tags: oauth, jmeter

Does anybody know how to send request with oauth_verifier parameter in Autorisation header and include it to base string (like oauth_token parameter etc.)?
oauth_verifier parameter specified in OAuth 1.0a http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step3

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may be not so simple as it will require some Java coding, but it is possible.

1. Direct solution: [Post a file in JMeter with Oauth signing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26264686/2897748)
2. Full walkthrough for both OAuth versions with options and explanations: [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)